# How to stop Visual Studio from opening memcpy assembly code whenever I step into a function with F11?

Tags: c, visual-studio, clang

I am compiling with clang on windows using the -O0 and -g flags. I have "Just My Code" enabled in the Visual Studio settings, yet every time I step into a function where I pass a struct or just enough parameters for the compiler to decide to put a memcpy, Visual Studio
shows me the memcpy assembly, so I have to go back, open the function on my own and Ctrl+F10 to it.

Here is the assembly it steps into:

```
        mov      rax, rcx                                        ; pre-set the return value
        lea      r10, OFFSET __ImageBase                         ; pre-set the image base to be used in table based branching
        cmp      r8, 15                                          ; dispatch to code handling block sizes of 16 bytes or more
        ja       MoveAbove15                                     ; fall-thru to code handling length of 15 bytes or less
```

I want to make it just step into the function instead of opening memcpy.asm.

Comment: I didn’t downvote but you didn’t even ask a question here.

Comment: @SafelyFast thanks for the feedback, I clarified it a bit